# Create checkboxes from a list and add to winform

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I need to add  alist of checkboxes, i retrieve them from a list named: Checklist.

How can i loops through and add them?

For the moment i use this:

```
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.Left = 50;
    chk.Text = "Check Box Test";
    chk.Name = "chkTest";
    this.Controls.Add(chk);
```

Comment: just surround your code with a for loop and increment left by `50 + (i * 50)`

Comment: but i need that the code to take the values from my list

Comment: Thats where the loop comes in

Comment: You lack basic knowledge of your problem. Search for "winforms dynamically add controls" and similar, then read about your problem, web is full of results that will help you learn on this topic.

Comment: dear, i don't know how to do it, i know the foreach loop but not to modify the code, please help

Comment: @MAL you don't show enough code -- there is nothing about the list you want to loop through so there is little to no way to help you

Comment: I'm not sure how much more help I can give because I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do, are you just trying to add checkboxes from an existing list of checkboxes or do you have a list with values that you wish to create new checkboxes from

Comment: so, i have the  Checklist which is an array, that contains Name and Text, i need to loop through it so i can create different checkboxes dynamically

Comment: So what type are the elements in CheckList? your own class?

Comment: yes, it's my own class...

Comment: @MAL How do you expect somebody to help if you say it is an array you want to loop through but then fail to say its your own object type and then fail to include that object definition? Update your question with enough information or you will probably not get the help you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking something like:

```
List <CheckBox> CheckBoxes=new List <CheckBox> ();

foreach (var box in Checklist)
{
 CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
 chk.Left = 50;
 chk.Text = box.Text;
 chk.Name = box.NAme;
 CheckBoxes.Add(chk);
}
```

I dont know the type of your Cheklist , you can set it in the foreach accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using your own class you need to loop through it and use it as any other loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < CheckList.Count; i++)
{
    TheTypeOfWhateverIsInCheckList c = CheckList[i];
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Text = c.WhateverPropertyIsAString;
    cb.Left = 50 + (i * 50);
    this.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```